# How to loop through JSON data with python and output a set of data for each dictionary and increment a sequence number that resets with each output?

Tags: json, python-2.7, loops, python-requests

I have a script that makes an API call and receives JSON data with employees and their time punches in a timecard system.  The end goal is to parse this data down to what I need and then insert that data into a sql table. The problem is what I have so far is only generating the desired output for one employee instead of all of them.

I've tried loops and attempted to create new dictionaries etc but each has their drawbacks for what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is the JSON output that I'm trying to parse down:

```
[
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "07:00:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "*************************",
            "EmployeeId": null,
            "FirstName": "Nicholas",
            "FullName": "Nicholas ******",
            "Id": 346186,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "******",
            "Username": "*******"
        },
        "Hours": 7.0,
        "Id": 13026137,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-19T07:49:00",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "*****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-19T14:49:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 7.0
    }
]
[
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "05:00:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "********",
            "EmployeeId": null,
            "FirstName": "Test",
            "FullName": "Test MBS",
            "Id": 346188,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "MBS",
            "Username": "testmbs"
        },
        "Hours": 5.0,
        "Id": 13026141,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-19T09:49:00",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-19T14:49:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 5.0
    }
]
[
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "05:00:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "starlord@email.com",
            "EmployeeId": "080097",
            "FirstName": "Peter",
            "FullName": "Peter Quill",
            "Id": 346968,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "Quill",
            "Username": "starlord"
        },
        "Hours": 5.0,
        "Id": 12970292,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-18T08:43:00",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-18T13:43:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 5.0
    },
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "01:16:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "starlord@email.com",
            "EmployeeId": "080097",
            "FirstName": "Peter",
            "FullName": "Peter Quill",
            "Id": 346968,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "Quill",
            "Username": "starlord"
        },
        "Hours": 1.267,
        "Id": 12983841,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-19T08:00:00",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-19T09:16:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 1.267
    },
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "03:00:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "starlord@email.com",
            "EmployeeId": "080097",
            "FirstName": "Peter",
            "FullName": "Peter Quill",
            "Id": 346968,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "Quill",
            "Username": "starlord"
        },
        "Hours": 3.0,
        "Id": 13007880,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-19T13:43:00",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-19T16:43:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 3.0
    },
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "04:00:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "starlord@email.com",
            "EmployeeId": "080097",
            "FirstName": "Peter",
            "FullName": "Peter Quill",
            "Id": 346968,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "Quill",
            "Username": "starlord"
        },
        "Hours": 4.0,
        "Id": 13022834,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.267,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-19T17:21:00",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-19T21:21:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 3.733
    }
]
[
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "15:33:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "****",
            "EmployeeId": "080098",
            "FirstName": "Kelly",
            "FullName": "Kelly ****",
            "Id": 346187,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "****",
            "Username": "****"
        },
        "Hours": 15.55,
        "Id": 12963731,
        "JobCodeId": 17673,
        "JobCodeName": "Test dept 1",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-18T08:27:00",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 2,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Approved",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-19T00:00:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 15.55
    },
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "04:27:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "****",
            "EmployeeId": "080098",
            "FirstName": "Kelly",
            "FullName": "Kelly ****",
            "Id": 346187,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "****",
            "Username": "****"
        },
        "Hours": 4.45,
        "Id": 12974763,
        "JobCodeId": 17673,
        "JobCodeName": "Test dept 1",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-19T00:00:00",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "Shift automatically closed after 20 hours.",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 2,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Approved",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-19T04:27:06.677",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "Shift automatically closed after 20 hours.",
        "RegularHours": 4.45
    },
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "05:00:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "kellyw@marinercomputer.com",
            "EmployeeId": "080098",
            "FirstName": "Kelly",
            "FullName": "Kelly ****",
            "Id": 346187,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "****",
            "Username": "****"
        },
        "Hours": 5.0,
        "Id": 12980029,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 5,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Time Recorded",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-19T07:13:32.12",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-19T12:13:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 5.0
    },
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "10:00:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "****",
            "EmployeeId": "080098",
            "FirstName": "Kelly",
            "FullName": "Kelly ****",
            "Id": 346187,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "****",
            "Username": "****"
        },
        "Hours": 10.0,
        "Id": 13064117,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 5,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Time Recorded",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-25T08:15:22.057",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 2,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Approved",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-25T18:15:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "Shift automatically closed after 10 hours.",
        "RegularHours": 10.0
    },
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": null,
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "****",
            "EmployeeId": "080098",
            "FirstName": "Kelly",
            "FullName": "Kelly ****",
            "Id": 346187,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "****",
            "Username": "****"
        },
        "Hours": null,
        "Id": 13079310,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 5,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Time Recorded",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-26T06:32:03.1",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": null,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": null,
        "PunchOutDateTime": null,
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": null,
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 0.0
    },
    {
        "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
        "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
        "BreakMinutes": 0,
        "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
        "Duration": "09:30:00",
        "Employee": {
            "Email": "****",
            "EmployeeId": "080098",
            "FirstName": "Kelly",
            "FullName": "Kelly ****",
            "Id": 346187,
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastName": "****",
            "Username": "****"
        },
        "Hours": 9.5,
        "Id": 13084304,
        "JobCodeId": null,
        "JobCodeName": "",
        "LocationId": null,
        "LocationName": "",
        "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
        "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
        "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
        "PTOHours": null,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-21T06:30:00",
        "PunchInImageUrl": "",
        "PunchInIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchInLatitude": null,
        "PunchInLongitude": null,
        "PunchInNotes": "",
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
        "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
        "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-21T16:00:00",
        "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
        "PunchOutIpAddress": "****",
        "PunchOutLatitude": null,
        "PunchOutLongitude": null,
        "PunchOutNotes": "",
        "RegularHours": 9.5
    }
]
```

As you can see it's a lot of data and this is only 4 employees over a 7 day period which could also potentially be longer. This chunk of json is output by this code:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('****.azure-api.net')
conn.request("GET", "/timecard/GetByPayPeriod/525117?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
tcdata = json.loads(data)

timecard_dict = {}
for timecard in tcdata:
    tcid = timecard['Id']
    timecard_dict.update({"Id": tcid})


    for key in timecard_dict.keys():
        id_no = str(timecard_dict['Id'])
        tcurl = ("/time/timecard/" + id_no + "?%s")
        conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('****.azure-api.net')
        conn.request("GET", tcurl % params, "{body}", headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        tcldata = response.read()
        parsed = json.loads(tcldata)
        print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

My attempt to go through this data and get the values I want is this:

```
timepunches_dict = parsed

def employee_punch_data():
    curr_date = None
    for punch in timepunches_dict:
        j = 1 if curr_date != punch['PunchInDateTime'][1:10] else j + 1

        emp_id = punch['Employee']['EmployeeId']
        emp_name = punch['Employee']['FullName']
        curr_date = punch['PunchInDateTime'][1:10]
        if punch['PunchInDateTime'] is not None:
            punch_in_sql = punch['PunchInDateTime'].replace('T', ' ')
        if punch['PunchOutDateTime'] is not None:
            punch_out_sql = punch['PunchOutDateTime'].replace('T', ' ')

        if today in punch_in_sql:
            if j == 1: 
                print(emp_id, today, emp_name)

            print(emp_id, today, j, punch_in_sql, punch_out_sql)
employee_punch_data()
```

The idea is to get one line that has data that will be inserted into a header table and then each of their punches for a corresponding day in sequence of each punch in and punch out. As in the first set is sequence number 1, the next set is sequence number 2 etc.  My output currently is:

```
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', u'Kelly ****')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 00:00:00', u'2019-06-19 04:27:06.677')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 2, u'2019-06-19 07:13:32.12', u'2019-06-19 12:13:00')
```

But what I was hoping to get is:

```
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', u'Nicholas ****')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 07:49:00', u'2019-06-19 14:49:00')

(u'080098', '2019-06-19', u'Test MBS')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 09:49:00', u'2019-06-19 14:49:00')

(u'080098', '2019-06-19', u'Peter Quill')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 08:00:00', u'2019-06-19 09:16:00')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 2, u'2019-06-19 13:43:00', u'2019-06-19 16:43:00')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 3, u'2019-06-19 17:21:00', u'2019-06-19 21:21:00')

(u'080098', '2019-06-19', u'Kelly ****')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 00:00:00', u'2019-06-19 04:27:06.677')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 2, u'2019-06-19 07:13:32.12', u'2019-06-19 12:13:00')
```

Basically instead of printing out these values my code will insert them into the sql database which I've had working I just need to get it the data it needs.  Where am I going wrong?  I suspect that I am perhaps overwriting data and only getting the last output or perhaps my loop is resetting to start over with each employee.  Where am I going wrong here? Or perhaps the better questions is, is this even possible? Should the function operate inside an iterated loop somehow? Apologies for how long this post has become.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone looks at this and wants to know how to do this I got this to work and this is the code

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('buddypunch.azure-api.net')
conn.request("GET", "/timecard/GetByPayPeriod/525117?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
tcdata = json.loads(data)

timecard_list = []
for timecard in tcdata:
    tcid = str(timecard['Id'])
    timecard_list.append(tcid)


for key in timecard_list:
    tcurl = ("/time/timecard/" + key + "?%s")
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('buddypunch.azure-api.net')
    conn.request("GET", tcurl % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    tcldata = response.read()
    parsed = json.loads(tcldata)
    timepunches_dict = parsed

    curr_date = None
    for punch in timepunches_dict:
        j = 1 if curr_date != punch['PunchInDateTime'][1:10] else j + 1

        emp_id = punch['Employee']['EmployeeId']
        emp_name = punch['Employee']['FullName']
        curr_date = punch['PunchInDateTime'][1:10]
        punch_in_sql = punch['PunchInDateTime'].replace('T', ' ')
        punch_out_sql = punch['PunchOutDateTime'].replace('T', ' ')

        if today in punch_in_sql:
            if j == 1:
            # ONLY RUN FOR FIRST ITERATION 
                print(emp_id, today, emp_name)

        # RUN FOR ALL ITERATIONS
            print(emp_id, today, j, punch_in_sql, punch_out_sql)

conn.close()
```

Frankly accessing the data from the timecard dictionary was a pain so I just made it a list and appended the individual tcid's and then just iterating through that list to get the data from the API. Additionally instead of trying to run a function I just made it a for loop inside the existing loop and this ended up solving the issues yielding the exact output I was expecting:

```
(u'080099', '2019-06-19', u'Nicholas ****')
(u'080099', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 07:49:00', u'2019-06-19 14:49:00')
(u'080100', '2019-06-19', u'Test MBS')
(u'080100', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 09:49:00', u'2019-06-19 14:49:00')
(u'080097', '2019-06-19', u'Peter Quill')
(u'080097', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 08:00:00', u'2019-06-19 09:16:00')
(u'080097', '2019-06-19', 2, u'2019-06-19 13:43:00', u'2019-06-19 16:43:00')
(u'080097', '2019-06-19', 3, u'2019-06-19 17:21:00', u'2019-06-19 21:21:00')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', u'Kelly ****')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 00:00:00', u'2019-06-19 04:27:06.677')
(u'080098', '2019-06-19', 2, u'2019-06-19 07:13:32.12', u'2019-06-19 12:13:00')
```